# Trouble adding tabs in identity popup JS API

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

**May 28 Edit**

I have edited my code a bit and have come up with a fix to the tab container, however I am now having troubles getting my attributes to show when I click on one of my service layers.  This is what I have so far

```
    var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(null, domConstruct.create("div"));
    infoWindow.startup();
    map.infoWindow.resize(300,300);

//Create info template to hold the content inside
var vliTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();
vliTemplate.setTitle("VLI");
vliTemplate.setContent(getWindowContent);

function getWindowContent(graphic) {
//VQO
//make a tab container
var tc = new dijit.layout.TabContainer({
style:"width:100%;height:100%;",
useMenu: false,
useSlider:false,
}, dojo.create("div"));

//add content pane 1 and 2 - these are the tabs
var cp1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
title: "Current",
content: "Visual: <tr><b>VLI Number:</b> <td>" + graphic.attributes.Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_CFLBarea + "</tr></td>"
});
var cp2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
title: "Approved",
content: "<br><tr><b>VQO: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_EVQO_CD}</tr></td>"
});


tc.addChild(cp1);
tc.addChild(cp2);
return tc.domNode;
}
```

As you see my cp1 and cp2 have different ways of showing my attributes (in order to try and find something that works) cp1 "Current" tab when clicked on reads "Undefined" as the attribute information, and cp2 "Approved" tab shows text written as

**VQO:** Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_EVQO_CD

Now i'm trying to figure out how to properly get my attributes to display in the appropriate tab pane!

**May 22**

I have a ArcGIS JS API map created with an InfoTemplate popup to display attributes but I need to have a tab in my popup window so that I can display different attributes from the same service.  For example on one tab I will have "Current" attributes, and in the other tab I will have "Approved" attributes.  This is my code for my InfoTemplate, but I don't know how to wrap the tab function around what I currently have displayed.

```
var vliTemplate = new InfoTemplate(
"Visual", "<tr><b>VLI Number:</b> <td>${VLI_VLI_NO} </tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>VQO: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_EVQO_CD}</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>VAC: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_VAC_FIN_CD}</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>CFLB Area: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_CFLBarea:NumberFormat(places:0)} Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>THLB Area: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_THLBarea:NumberFormat(places:0)} Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Total Area: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_HA:NumberFormat(places:0)} Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Greened Up Height: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_Height:NumberFormat(places:0)}m</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Not Greened Up CFLB: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_Not_Greened_Up_Ha:NumberFormat(places:0)} Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Greened Up CFLB: </b><td>${greened:compare6}Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Maximum Target Percent: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_Pct_tgt:NumberFormat(places:0)}%</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Maximum Target: </b><td>${Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_Target_Ha:NumberFormat(places:0)} Ha</tr></td>"+
"<br><tr><b>Surplus/Deficit: </b><td>${surplusDef1:changeColor6}</tr></td>")

compare6 = function (value,key,data) {
 var result = "", diff;

 switch (key) {
    case "greened":
      diff = data.Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_HA - data.Tbl_ResultSummary_VQO_Not_Greened_Up_Ha;
      break;

}

   result = diff.toFixed();
   return result;

};
```

I have been looking at the sample on https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/find_drilldown.html but I'm stumped....